# Is there a way to make the image alt tags print out using this javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

It prints the innerHTML of the "printme" div, and I'd like it to also print any alt tags on the page as well:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
  var win=null;
  function printIt(printThis)
  {
    win = window.open();
    self.focus();
    win.document.open();
    win.document.write('<'+'html'+'><'+'head'+'><'+'style'+'>');
    win.document.write('body, td { font-family: Verdana; font-size: 10pt;}');
    win.document.write('<'+'/'+'style'+'><'+'/'+'head'+'><'+'body'+'>');
    win.document.write(printThis);
    win.document.write('<'+'/'+'body'+'><'+'/'+'html'+'>');
    win.document.close();
    win.print();
    win.close();
      }
    </script>
```

body html:
        
        
        
        Print
        
        
        Only this part of the page is printed

Comment: First, what's an "alt tag"? Do you mean the `<img>`'s `alt` attribute's value? And, why not declare the string as a variable and then `win.documet.write()` it all in one go?

Answer (score 0):

Use "getAttribute" if you are talking about an img tag, which I would assume you are.

```
var imgAlt = document.getElementById("theImageID").getAttribute("alt");
document.write(imgAlt);
```

Example: http://codepen.io/KennyGHanson/pen/JBsiw